# React: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have following return statement thats giving error `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` Any idea what is wrong?

```
return (
      <div>
       {(this.props.someProp !== undefined) ? (    
        <Header ..something.. />
        <MyElement
         ...something...
        />
      ) : (
        <card>
        </card>
      )}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: render() method must return a single JSX element, if you have multiple elements, they need to be surrounded by a single element such as 'div'.

Comment: @FinbarrO'B I have it in div right?

Comment: Are you using conditional operator  ?

Comment: It's not really valid JSX in your example, as @Kind user noted in their answer

Comment: yes updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you miss the wrapper in conditional statement.

```
return (
  <div>
    {(this.props.someProp !== undefined) ? 
      <div>
       <Header ..something.. />
       <MyElement
         ...something...
       />
     </div>
       : 
      <card>
        something
      </card>
    }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Are you enclosing the `Header` and `MyElement` in a `div` ?

Answer (score 3):

React element has to return only one element.

Do this

```
return (
    <div>
       <Card1 />
       <Card2 />
    </div>
)
```

Instead

```
return (  
    <Card1 />
    <Card2 />
)
```