# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Here is my code:

```
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={props.theme}>

        <section className={classes.loginForm}>
            {
            mode === "LOGIN"
            ?
            <LoginForm theme={props.theme} />
            <br/> <br/>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setMode("SIGNUP")}>
                SIGNUP?
            </Button>
            :
            <SignUpForm theme={props.theme} />
            <br/><br/>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setMode("SIGNUP")}>
                SIGNUP?
            </Button>
            }
        </section>

    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

The error appears at the first character of the opening tag for the breakline HTML element. I do not understand why this is happening as I have code elsewhere that uses the same principle and has no errors at all.

Comment: And _are_ those elements wrapped in an enclosing tag?

Comment: The problem is exactly what the message tells you - you need another enclosing tag around each possible value of your conditional expression.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I have put the enclosing tags around the breaklines. Are you referring to the whole conditional statement within the curly braces as I have not done that before and it has worked fine. I also have the section enclosing tags. The basic code is repeated with both of the outcomes with certain text changes and the other code has no errors.

Comment: You have not done this and had it work before. The `<br/>`s and their "siblings" are **not** surrounded by enclosing tags, hence the error.

Comment: I have. The only difference with this code is that it includes Material UI. the enclosing tags should be the section tags for, which are there. If I remove the `<br/>`s and the button it works completely fine.

Comment: Yes, because then you only have one element which doesn't need an enclosing tag. Then when you put the adjacent elements, you need the enclosing tag. That's what the error says.

Comment: I get it now. I just didn't look at the jsx that it outputted as a return as in returns you can only return one thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290251/react-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These elements, inside the curly braces, need to be wrapped inside of a `<React.Fragment />` (`<>` and `</>` for short)

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

**Your code:**

```js
 {
            mode === "LOGIN"
            ?
            <LoginForm theme={props.theme} />
            <br/> <br/>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setMode("SIGNUP")}>
                SIGNUP?
            </Button>
            :
            <SignUpForm theme={props.theme} />
            <br/><br/>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setMode("SIGNUP")}>
                SIGNUP?
            </Button>
 }
```

**Corrected code:**

```js
{
    mode === "LOGIN"
    ?
    <>
        <LoginForm theme={props.theme} />
        <br/> <br/>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setMode("SIGNUP")}>
            SIGNUP?
        </Button>
    </>
    :
    <>
        <SignUpForm theme={props.theme} />
        <br/><br/>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setMode("SIGNUP")}>
            SIGNUP?
        </Button>
    </>
}
```